# Shortcut key unkown

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

What is that icon next to print? I have tried multiple keys and I cannot figure out what that icon is suppose to be

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the **Alt** key. If you check under the Keyboard > Windows category
**Alt** + **F4** closes the current window and it has the same icon.